# How can I declare different form types in Symfony?

Tags: forms, symfony

When I define a Form Type for an arbitrary Entity, let's say `User`, I can then add a UserFormType class as follow,

```
class UserFormType 
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // ...
        $builder->add('email', 'text');
    }
}
```

What if I want to define another form type for the User:

- What are good naming conventions in this case?
- Where to put the logic? Into a separate FormType Class or as another method into the existing one?

Comment: Just create another type, like `AlternativeUserType` which will bind the user. Just make sure it fits all User's `Constraints`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define as many Types as you need for each entity.

If I need more than one Type, I usually have the "standard" entitynameType and for the other ones I attach some keyword related to the place I am using it. For example if one form is only for update the status UserStatusType.

You have to use another class because you are extending AbstractType and the method that build the form must be buildForm.

If you need to adapt your form depending the kind of user you have you can use an event listener
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html